# Input  type="radio"  Картинка вместо кнопки в Firefox

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. 
Css к input

```
input.styled  {
    background: url(img/bitcoin.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width:173px;
    height:75px;
    appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    outline:none;

}

input.styled:checked {
  background-position-y: -193px;
}
input.styled:hover  {
    background-position-y: -100px;
}
```

В хроме выглядит нормально а в FF вот так  http://pastexen.com/i/Gr6HrBJER6.png

Что для FF добавить нужно в css?

Comment: @RattleSneyk, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Comment: Так я вставлял как код, но почему то не применилось - уже не в первый раз такое.

Answer (score 1):

Свойство [background-position-y](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position-y) является не кроссбраузерным. Пользуйся более универсальным [background-position](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position). Всегда смотри на таблицу кросс-браузерной поддержки: http://take.ms/7qO8t

Comment: Не. Дело не в этом, хотя тоже не правильно написал - согласен. 
Как я понял -moz-appearance:none; не правильно работает.

Comment: @RattleSneyk, я что-то вообще [не наблюдаю значения "none"][1] для этого свойства.

   [1]:http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-css3-ui-20030703/#appearance

Comment: http://www.xiper.net/manuals/css/properties/appearance.html